# Excel 2010 Countif Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I'm trying to make a spreadsheet to display stock orders. I am including both executed and unexecuted orders, but I'm trying to display how many orders did or did not execute using Countif. My orders are in a table, column G displays whether it did or didn't execute (It has a heading, don't know if that matters). I am referencing a sheet named Transactions.

My formula looks like this:
=COUNTIF(Transactions!G:G,G:G=Executed)

Not sure where to go from here. If I need to give more details please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Have you tried the "Help On this Function" for COUNTIF?  Your example is covered as the initial example in the documentation.

Comment: Sorry for the noobie question, do you know how to access that?

Comment: Press the Fx next to your formula (that is erroring), and there is a link in the lower-left to a guide on how to use the function.  The question is now answered, but this is a good practice for learning/troubleshooting functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the [criteria](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx) `G:G=Executed` -

`=COUNTIF(Transactions!G:G,"Executed")`